# Calcular interés compuesto en PHP7

Tags: php, revisión-de-código, matemáticas, depuración

Quiero calcular el interés compuesto a partir de un capital X, pero el script que he encontrado aquí [Ejemplo -Calcular Interés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380352/calculating-a-compound-interest-in-php) 
no me termina de funcionar. Este es mi código:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head><meta charset="UTF-8"></head>
        <title> Cálculo de intereses</title>
        <body>
            <center><h3>Introduce el capital, el porcentaje de interés  y el tiempo en alos</h3></center>
            <form name="Formulario" method="post" action="ejercicio6.php">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Capital incial:
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="float" name="capital" value="Cantidad X" required></td>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        Tiempo (años):
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="number" name="tiempo" value="1" max="100" required></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td>Porcentaje:</td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td><input type="number" name="porcen" value="5" max="100" required></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="Enviar">
                        <input type="reset" name="Reestablecer">
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

El **PHP:**

```
<?php
    //Declaración de variables
    $tiempo = $_POST['tiempo'];
    $porcen = $_POST['porcen'];
    $capital = $_POST['capital'];
    $n = 1; //periodos por año, lo dejo a uno pues no se especifica nada más en el ejercicio
    //Ejercicio
function interest($capital,$tiempo,$porcen,$n=1){
    $acumulado=0;
    if ($tiempo > 1){
            $acumulado=interest($capital,$tiempo-1,$porcen,$n);
            }
    $acumulado1 = $capital;
    $acumulado = $acumulado1* pow(1 + $porcen/(100 * $n),$n);
    return $acumulado;
    }
echo "el interés acumulado es : ". interest($capital,$tiempo,$porcen,$n);
?>
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa "no me termina de funcionar"? ¿Fallo del intérprete (qué fallo, no salen resultados, resultados incorrectos (qué resultado esperas y qué resultado obtienes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No `"funciona"` como esperas dado que no haces el llamado de la función que hace el cálculo del interés  `interest`  además tu variable `$acumulado3` no aparece por ningún lado , no podrías acceder a las variables que usas dentro de la `función` porque están en otro ámbito , Una opción sería solo modificar la impresión final  `echo "el interes acumulado es $acumulado3";`  por

```
echo "el interés acumulado es : ". interest($capital,$tiempo,$porcen,$n);
```

**UPDATE** Tener en cuenta que es una función `recursiva`, además es error de edición que puede surgir  (es Normal) , su función quedaría así.

```
<?php 
 //Declaración de variables
$tiempo = $_POST['tiempo'];
$porcen = $_POST['porcen'];
$capital = $_POST['capital'];
$n = 1; //periodos por año, lo dejo a uno pues no se especifica nada más en el ejercicio

function interest($capital,$tiempo,$porcen,$n){
    $acumulado=0;
    if ($tiempo > 1){
            $acumulado=interest($capital,$tiempo-1,$porcen,$n);
   }
    $acumulado+= $capital;
    $acumulado = $acumulado * pow(1 + $porcen/(100 * $n),$n);
    return $acumulado;
 }
 echo "el interes acumulado es".interest($capital,$tiempo,$porcen,$n);
 ?>
```

Comment: Ahora lo edito, es que no he copiado la versión que iba  a poner, era otra anterior

Comment: Con la nueva actualización de la pregunta, cuál es el error que presenta?.

Comment: El error radica en que al pasar los años no varía la cantidad total

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta , espero pueda ayudarte.

Comment: ¡Solucionado, señor, es usted un grande! Si me explica el ```$acumulado+= $capital;``` se lo agradaceré bastante

Comment: Eso es igual a tener `$acumulado = $acumulado +$capital ;` al valor acumulado por meses que devuelve la recursividad se le suma el capital para luego en base a ese monto total. Sacar el interés.